# Export multiple Layer Definition Files (qlr)

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with approximately 400 tables. I need to generate Layer definition files (qlr) in QGIS for each individual table. Making this manually would take huge amount of time, so I would like to make a batch process or a python script, that does it for me.

Is there anyone here that can help me in the right direction? :)

Comment: A QLR file is an XML file, so i guess it would probably be possible I'm surprised to find no answer to this interesting question but i'm no expert in Python., as I suppose it mustn't be so hard, as the function to create a single qlr file exists, it would probably be just a matter of looping this function on all layers available in a QGIS project for example...